# PyQt transform translate of pixmap having no affect

Tags: python, pyqt, transform, translate

I need to rotate and translate a QPixmap derived from an image
I can transform the pixmap using rotate but translate does not appear to move the image.
Can someone suggest changes to the example below to move the image to given x and y values?

To run the code, replace test.png with a convenient small image file.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui 

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFixedSize(640, 480)

        label = QLabel("PyQt5 label!")
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(label)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("test.png")
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        xform = QtGui.QTransform().translate(250,50)
        xform.rotate(12) 
        xformed_pixmap = pixmap.transformed(xform, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        label.setPixmap(xformed_pixmap)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using QTransforma to move the QPixmap you should move the QLabel:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QTransform
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFixedSize(640, 480)

        label = QLabel(self)
        label.move(250, 50)

        pixmap = QPixmap("test.png")
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        xform = QTransform()
        xform.rotate(12)
        xformed_pixmap = pixmap.transformed(xform, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        label.setPixmap(xformed_pixmap)
        label.adjustSize()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you,  your answer has addressed the question I asked,   I am curious why you added the adjustSize call,  is this needed if the pixmap is never scaled.

Comment: @MichaelM use adjustSize so that the QLabel takes the size of the QPixmap, by default the size of the QLabel does not take into account the content. Please read [ask] and [tour]